# Filter/Query Check boxes

Tags: image, google-sheets, filter, checkbox, google-query-language

Is there a way when creating a filter or query function to include the check-boxed columns as is instead of True and False values?
Thank you for your help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15agH1PBFGqpTJn5kZDR9_oKQ5fDQ0ADbU4r8WbJBtMc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A2:C8, IF(Sheet1!D2:D8=TRUE, 
 IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/DgTwvYi.png"),
 IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/8AxCgKZ.png"))}, Sheet1!A2:A8="Marez")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks very impressive. I like your trick. Is there a way to wrap it in the query function because I need to select certain columns not everything? Thank you so much for your help showing the header as well.

Comment: @user610125 query does not support pictures
but filter is as powerfull as query